# How to make conditional margin for hideable flex panels?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have initial html:

```css
body {
  background-color: grey;
}
.container{
  display: flex;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}
.panel{
  height: 100%;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-basis: 50%;
  color: white;
}
.left{
  background-color: green;
}
.left{
  margin-right: 8px;
}
.right{
  background-color: blue;
}
.hidden{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left panel ">left</div>
  <div class="right panel ">right</div>
</div>
```

It makes two panels of equal width with 8px margin between them. [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/myzgb52x/)

Looks:

[image: how it looks]

Then I need to hide right or left or both panels with hidden class.

I have new html ([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/56a2gq5h/1/)):

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="left panel ">left</div>
    <div class="right panel hidden">right</div>
</div>
```

Result:

[image]

How to remove margin if there is one panel and show margin if there are two panels?
I can't just move margin from left to right panel because I need possibility to hide both panels independently.

**UPD 1.** I can't remove panels from dom. It should use hidden class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it *without* removing the `panel` from DOM:

1. Instead of `margin-right` on the `left` panel, use `margin-left` on the `right` panel.
2. Use the below styles to get rid of the margin when either `left` or `right` has the class `hidden`:

```css
.container > .left.hidden + .right {
   margin-left:0;
}
```

See demo below:

```css
body {
  background-color: grey;
}
.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}
.panel {
  height: 100%;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-basis: 50%;
  color: white;
}
.left {
  background-color: green;
}
.right {
  background-color: blue;
  margin-left: 8px;
}
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
.container > .left.hidden + .right{
  margin-left:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left panel">left</div>
  <div class="right panel">right</div>
</div>
<br/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="left panel">left</div>
  <div class="right panel hidden">right</div>
</div>
<br/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="left panel hidden">left</div>
  <div class="right panel">right</div>
</div>
<br/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="left panel hidden">left</div>
  <div class="right panel hidden">right</div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you, your approach solves the problem. If you interested look please my own solution. It is very close but a bit different. Thank you again!

Answer (score 2):

Try using `+` selector. By using this selector only margin is added when the `.right` div is placed immediately after `.left` div:

```css
.left + .right {
  margin-left: 8px;
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: grey;
}
.container{
  display: flex;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  margin-bottom:20px;
}
.panel{
  height: 100%;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-basis: 50%;
  color: white;
}
.left{
  background-color: green;
}

.left + .right{
  margin-left:8px;
}
.right{
  background-color: blue;
}
.hidden{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left panel">left</div>
  <div class="right panel">right</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="left panel">left</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is my own version how to do it.
Advantage: no extra margin enable/disable. Margin is applied only when it is necessary.
Disadvantage: I'm afraid it is not very flexible.

```css
body {
  background-color: grey;
}
.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}
.panel {
  height: 100%;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-basis: 50%;
  color: white;
}
.left {
  background-color: green;
}
.right {
  background-color: blue;
}
.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.container .left:not(.hidden) + .right:not(.hidden){
  margin-left: 8px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left panel">left</div>
  <div class="right panel">right</div>
</div>
<br/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="left panel">left</div>
  <div class="right panel hidden">right</div>
</div>
<br/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="left panel hidden">left</div>
  <div class="right panel">right</div>
</div>
<br/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="left panel hidden">left</div>
  <div class="right panel hidden">right</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This's a nice one too :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `~` selector as well.

```css
.container > div ~ div {
  margin-left: 8px;
}
.container > .hidden + .right {
  margin-left: 0;
}
```

This will allow you to add some space if there are 2, 3, or more items in `.container`.

```css
body {
  background-color: grey;
}
.container{
  display: flex;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.panel{
  height: 100%;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-basis: 50%;
  color: white;
}
.left{
  background-color: green;
}
.right{
  background-color: blue;
}
.hidden{
  display: none;
}
.container > div ~ div {
  margin-left: 8px;
}
.container > .hidden + .right {
    margin-left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="left panel ">left</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="left panel ">left</div>
    <div class="right panel">right</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="left panel ">left</div>
    <div class="right panel">right</div>
    <div class="right panel">right</div>
</div>
```

Comment: It doesn't work if make left panel hidden. Right panel will have margin in this case.
And see UPD 1 - I can't modify dom and remove panel.